Doomed, telepathic, underground-living alien civilisation. They send an explorer who enters the mind of a baby on an aeroplane
This short story I read about 95 but it seemed to have been written some decades earlier.
An alien civilisation have been living underground, for many generation. They have only old stories about what life on the surface of a planet is like.
All their young are concieved by IVF and grow outside of wombs. I am pretty sure, but not certain, it was written before humans were capable of IVF. These people communicate with each other telepathically. They have several pairs of legs. I probably borrowed it in a Science Fiction anthology from a libray in the UK.The book was probably hardback.
Their entire species is slowly getting closer to extiction as their home cools down.
A traveller is trying to save his people. He sends his mind telepathically into the mind of a baby on an aeroplane. He is very troubled, that the body he is in, is so tiny, weak and non telepathic.He enters some adult minds temporarily to learn about Earth.
The traveller feels the concept of a mother loving her baby is an abomination. They decide to avoid humans and enter the minds of animals on an uninhabited island.
It was not the book K-PAX which also has aliens sending their consciousness into human bodies.

Thanks for that information. The book was probably hardback. I will add that to my question @JiminyCricket.

I remember being about ten years old when Louise Brown was born as a result of IVF. First 'test tube baby. "

Yes, that is the same story

"The Deep" by Isaac Asimov (from Galaxy magazine, 1952 and reprinted often)

A sentry sent by The Race to establish a teleport on Earth suffers
shock when exposed to unfamiliar aspects of human life, including
maternal bonding, weather changes, and the inability to communicate
telepathically.



In In Memory Yet Green, Asimov wrote that his motive in writing the
story was to deliberately test whether one could do anything in
science fiction, so he invented a society in which mother love was
considered obscene.

